# Using Derived string value from Main class to Test class

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I am new with Junit testing and trying to access the string value derived in main class (WebPage)into my test class (WebPageTest). When i instantiate new WebPage() into test class, i cannot access any values.
**I want to access PriceD string from main class into Test class but unable to**

Could anyone please tell me what i'm doing wrong here.
Thanks

///Main class

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;


import javax.swing.*;


public class WebPage {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/sadeedch/Downloads/chromedriver");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.woolworths.com.au/");
        WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.id("headerSearch"));
        name.click();
        name.sendKeys("fresh strawberry 250g");


        WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/wow-root/wow-app-layout/div/div[1]/shared-header/shared-core-header/header/shared-header-search/form/div/div/div[2]/button[2]"));
        //button.submit();
        button.click();

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        //Web element to locate price in Dollars
        WebElement priceDollars = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search-content\"]/div/wow-product-search-container/shared-grid/div/div[1]/shared-product-tile/section/div[1]/div/div[1]/shared-price/div/span[2]"));
        String priceD = priceDollars.getText(); // Grab Dollar price as string

        //Web element to locate price in Cents
        WebElement priceCents = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/wow-root/wow-app-layout/div/div[3]/main/wow-search-container/shared-layout-wrapper-tile/div/wow-product-search-container/shared-grid/div/div[1]/shared-product-tile/section/div[1]/div/div[1]/shared-price/div/div/span[2]"));
        String priceC = priceCents.getText();  // Grab Cents price as string

        System.out.println("Price of this Item is $" + priceD + "." + priceC);

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

** Test Class **

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class WebPageTest {

    @Test
    public void main() {
        WebPage web = new WebPage();

        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should not test main(){} method since that method is designed for running java programs. If you want to run the code inside the main method and get priceD value, you can change the code like following:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;


import javax.swing.*;


public class WebPage {
    public String testWebPage() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/sadeedch/Downloads/chromedriver");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.woolworths.com.au/");
        WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.id("headerSearch"));
        name.click();
        name.sendKeys("fresh strawberry 250g");


        WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/wow-root/wow-app-layout/div/div[1]/shared-header/shared-core-header/header/shared-header-search/form/div/div/div[2]/button[2]"));
        //button.submit();
        button.click();

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        //Web element to locate price in Dollars
        WebElement priceDollars = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search-content\"]/div/wow-product-search-container/shared-grid/div/div[1]/shared-product-tile/section/div[1]/div/div[1]/shared-price/div/span[2]"));
        String priceD = priceDollars.getText(); // Grab Dollar price as string

        //Web element to locate price in Cents
        WebElement priceCents = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/wow-root/wow-app-layout/div/div[3]/main/wow-search-container/shared-layout-wrapper-tile/div/wow-product-search-container/shared-grid/div/div[1]/shared-product-tile/section/div[1]/div/div[1]/shared-price/div/div/span[2]"));
        String priceC = priceCents.getText();  // Grab Cents price as string

        System.out.println("Price of this Item is $" + priceD + "." + priceC);

        driver.quit();
        
        // Returning priceD in here so you can use it in whereever you wanted
        return priceD;
    }
}
```

Then in your test class, you can call the method like this:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class WebPageTest {

    @Test
    public void main() {
        WebPage web = new WebPage();
        String priceD = web.testWebPage();
        // Use priceD as you need
        

    }
}
```

Like this way, when you call testWebPage by using `web.testWebPage();` the code in testWebPage() method will run and it will return priceD value.